# Why doesn't to set Checkbox column to Ultragrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I tried to add a checkbox column to Ultragrid.

But Ultragrid does not have a checkbox.
Just Checked or UnChecked Text...
Or True or False Text...

```
UltraGridColumn ugc = e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns.Add(key, caption);
ugc.DataType = typeof(bool);
ugc.Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.CheckBox;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv9vf.png)

Comment: Where are you adding your column? To make this work you should add your column in InitializeLayout event of the grid as shown here - https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawingrid~infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultragridcolumn~datatype.

Comment: I added to  InitializeLayout event of the grid.. T.T

Comment: adding this code, in version 18.2, works for me. There should be something else you are doing to remove the checkboxes

Comment: Ah... Sorry T.T my inf- version is 15.1... Perhaps.... Is there any code I need to add in this version?

Comment: I solved it! Thank you for your attention:D

Answer (score 0):

1. In the same form as your UltraGrid (ug) add an UltraCheckEditor (uchk)
2. Change the z-order of your Editor to hide it behind your grid.
3. Modify the appearance properties of your Editor to your tastes.
4. Add the following generic code:

```
    Private Sub FormatMyBooleanFields()
        uchk.CheckAlign = Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

        With ug.Rows.Band
            For i As Integer = 0 To .Columns.Count - 1
                If .Columns(i).DataType Is GetType(Boolean) Then
                    ug.Rows.Band.Columns(i).EditorComponent = uchk
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End Sub
```